# is it possible to style a value of an input text?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know if is possible to style a value of an input box... [such](http://jsfiddle.net/aCwhY/) as :

```
<input class="textBox" type="text" rel="Inserisci il <span style=" value="Inserisci il <span style='color:#c83243;'>titolo</span> per l’URL personalizzato" name="ctl00$InsertDati1$txtTitolo">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

but it doesnt render the span element. Any suggestions?

Comment: you mean the text inside the the `textBox`??

Comment: Hardly. See the "Related" section here to the right for dozens of similar questions, and unsatisfying answers. But tell me, are you really trying to insert a HTML `span` into an `input`? That won't work.

Comment: span was just an example! What I need is just a custom text into an input :) the Quentin solution rock, but on IE7 I've some troubles...

Answer (score 15):

You can style the content within an input box. For eg:

```
input{
    color:#ff0000;
    font: 1em/1.25em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

If you want to use placeholder content on the other hand, you can add a 'placeholder' attribute on the input tag like so:

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder='Title' />
```

Note that placeholders only work in browsers that support HTML5 and the placeholder attribute. If you want compatibility for older browsers and dont mind using some JQuery, you can use a JQuery plugin like [JQuery Watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/).

You can't however, place span elements within the `value` of an `input` tag.

Answer (score 10):

Using contentEditable attribute with div is very nice I think.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/scjnwrnf/
`<div contenteditable="true">This is a paragraph.<span style = "color:red"> It is editable. </span> Try to change this text.</div>`
Then you can hide input element and put plain text value from div into input value via JavaScript. 
Thanks penartur.

Answer (score 6):

No, it isn't possible.

Don't try to abuse the `value` attribute to provide a `<label>` for form controls. (And don't try to use the `rel` attribute for anything other than relationships on links for that matter).

Instead, use a real `<label>`. If you really want it to appear where the user is going to be typing, then:

1. Wrap the input and label in a container (e.g. a div)
2. Set `position: relative` on it to make it a containing block
3. Absolutely position the input on top of the label
4. Make the background colour of the input transparent
5. Add any other styling as desired

Comment: But only if I click on the text..clicking near the next it works also on IE7! Why?

Answer (score 5):

You can style the entire input box content, but cannot apply different styles to different parts of its content.

e.g. `<input style="color:red" value="all text is red"/>` is possible, but `<input value="<span style='color:red'>this text is red</span>, and <span style='color:red'>this text is red</span>">` is not.

Try to look at multi-line boxes with contenteditable feature instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's possible.. try it with a selector like this:

```css
input[value^="Your Value"] {
    Your styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is style the text with the input selector then style  it different input:focus. So the placeholder text will look different than the text someone types.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending the answer a bit more for fellow programmers to understand how it helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score -20):

Try using Twitter's bootstrap package - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap - you can easily achieve corner radius, inset shadows, nice hover and focus effects... You can also download "less-css" version - really flexible tool - but it's for more experienced users :)

Comment: Nothing there helps authors style *part* of a value.