# How to add HTML to <input> value attribute

Tags: html, css, attributes

I have an `<input>` element whose `value` attribute I want to be italicized text. I'd like to write

```
<input type="submit" value="<em>Text</em>" name="text" class="button">
```

but that doesn't work since the HTML inside the attribute doesn't render. I know I can solve this with CSS using `font-style: italic;` but I've heard that isn't good form. So, mostly out of curiosity, what would be the "proper" way to do this?

Comment: Using CSS is most definitely the proper way to style the appearance of text in input elements (as long as it's not inline)

Comment: Who said it wasn't good form to use font style?

Comment: Using css improves readability by a lot. It also adds some re usability to your classes

Comment: i mean, you could use those tags if you used button tags, but... yeah... nothing wrong with using css to... style things... kinda what it's for

Answer (score 3):

You could define a new rule for your case using `class` for example `.btn-italic` :

```
.btn-italic{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

HTML will be :

```
<input type="submit" value="Text" name="text" class="button btn-italic">
```

Hope this helps.

```css
.btn-italic{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Text" name="text" class="button btn-italic">
```

Answer (score 1):

From your use of the `<em>`, I suspect you might've heard that the tag is better than styling because it really marks the enclosed text as emphasized.

However, that doesn't apply here. While the enclosed text may be rendered as italic, that's not the point of the tag. The tag is there to point out the **function** of the text rather than to say something about how it should be visualized. The `<em>` tag points out that emphasis should be placed on this particular piece of text. This is an important concept when it comes to accessibility browsers such as screen readers. If the text was only made italic with styling, the screen reader wouldn't know for what purpose it's made italic.

With buttons however, the function of the text is simply to be a label for the button and thus any desired style of the text is purely presentational and should be done with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can do it is with CSS that you mentioned. Seems like this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326352/is-it-possible-to-style-a-value-of-an-input-text) was asking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make the value in your button bold.
Firstly let your HTML attributes be:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Put the below attribute inside your CSS file or your CSS style:

```
input[type="submit"]{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```